# Getting access deny error while modifying app.config file in Win7

Tags: app-config

I am using app.config to store application configuration settings, also I allow user to updated these settings run-time. This is working fine in Win Xp but in Win 7 I am getting access deny error when try to modify app.config. If I run application as administrator than its work fine. I am using ConfigurationManager to update app.config.

The application should allow to modify settings to normal use also.

Comment: Is the application stored in a user (aka appdata) directory?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this solution as it may help
[How to get admin privileges for editing app.config in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147171/how-to-get-admin-privileges-for-editing-app-config-in-c)

Comment: Thank you Dave.

I already tried this, it's working fine but then I am not able to meet another requirement where I have to accept value for configuration paramters while setup (visual studio installer .msi using custom action) and update those value to configuration.

When I modify settings as below it doesn't reflected. I dig into this and found that user.config under AppData not generated until I run application and modify one of the setting. And so while setup it unable to modify/write.

Properties.Settings.Default.Foo = "bar";
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();