# Access Permission for app.config on Installshield

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

On my windows form application i'm saving some application theme information to app.config `<appSettings/>` section i used read app.config like this

```
 var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(Application.ExecutablePath);
```

it works. but once i created installer using installshield when i save settings it shows file access permission denied because app install in to `C:\Program Files (x86)`

how to enable access permission on app.config when i use installshield or if the way i doing it wrong what is the best practices.

Regards

Comment: Are you sure the permission error is due to the app existing in "Program Files (x86)"?  I suspect the error occurs because the user doesn't have permission to modify files in that Program Files folder.  Also, are you suggesting that the app itself writes to the app.config file?

Comment: yeah app writes to app.config but on exception message it says  An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lush\gmjyyayu.tmp' is denied. (C:\Program Files (x86)\Lush\SmsAlertRemainder.exe.config) ---> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Lush\gmjyyayu.tmp' is denied.

Comment: That doesn't rule out what I suspected.  If you tried to edit the app.config (yourapp.exe.config) directly on the target machine, in notepad for example, does it allow you to save your changes to the file, or do you also get a permissions error?  If so, there's the problem.

Comment: Yeah it won't allow to edit in notepad even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applications run by only an administrator user will have the modify permission on files in the Program Files folder (or Program Files x86).  For this reason, it's best practice to store settings that will be saved by the application in a separate settings file, stored in the user's AppData folder.  Different users can then have their own values, stored in their individual file, and the app.config file can be used to store default values for all users.

The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147171/how-to-get-admin-privileges-for-editing-app-config-in-c) post gives instructions on how to implement a mechanism of storing User Settings.