# Custom Configuration Section can only be saved/modified while running as administrator?

Tags: c#, configuration, app-config, configuration-files

I wrote a custom configuration section, collection, and element to add/modify to my app.config.  All seems to be going well and it works perfectly running in Visual Studio.  However, when I install the application and it comes time to save the new data to the custom config section, the following exception is thrown:

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unable to save config to file '{path to config file}'
```

The interesting part is that if I run the application in administrator mode, everything works fine. Is there any reason it would only work as administrator?

**EDIT:**

I should note that I don't think its a permissons issue because a) we have other apps that modify the `<applicationSettings>` of their app.configs just fine there and b) log4net is able to write its log file just fine there.

Custom Config Element:

```
public class AuditorColorElement : ConfigurationElement
{
    public AuditorColorElement()
    {
    }

    public AuditorColorElement(Color color, string auditor)
    {
        Color = color;
        Auditor = auditor;
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty(nameof(Color), IsRequired = true, IsKey = true)]
    public Color Color
    {
        get { return (Color)base[nameof(Color)]; }
        set { this[nameof(Color)] = value; }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty(nameof(Auditor), IsRequired = true)]
    public string Auditor
    {
        get { return (string)base[nameof(Auditor)]; }
        set { this[nameof(Auditor)] = value; }
    }
}
```

Custom Config Section:

```
[ConfigurationCollection(typeof(AuditorColorElement))]
public class AuditorColorElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection, IEnumerable<AuditorColorElement>
{
    internal const string PropertyName = "AuditorColors";

    public AuditorColorElementCollection() : base()
    {
    }

    public AuditorColorElementCollection(AuditorColorElementCollection collection)
    {
        foreach (AuditorColorElement element in collection)
        {
            Add(element);
        }
    }

    public override ConfigurationElementCollectionType CollectionType
    {
        get
        {
            return ConfigurationElementCollectionType.AddRemoveClearMapAlternate;
        }
    }

    protected override string ElementName
    {
        get
        {
            return PropertyName;
        }
    }

    public AuditorColorElement this[int idx]
    {
        get { return (AuditorColorElement)BaseGet(idx); }
    }

    protected override bool IsElementName(string elementName)
    {
        return elementName.Equals(PropertyName,
        StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override bool IsReadOnly()
    {
        return false;
    }

    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new AuditorColorElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((AuditorColorElement)(element)).Color;
    }

    public void Add(AuditorColorElement element)
    {
        BaseAdd(element);
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        BaseClear();
    }

    public void Remove(AuditorColorElement element)
    {
        BaseRemove(element.Color);
    }

    public void RemoveAt(int index)
    {
        BaseRemoveAt(index);
    }

    public void Remove(Color color)
    {
        BaseRemove(color);
    }

    public object GetKey(object key)
    {
        return BaseGet(key);
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(object key)
    {
        return GetKey(key) != null ? true : false;
    }

    public new IEnumerator<AuditorColorElement> GetEnumerator()
    {
        foreach (var key in this.BaseGetAllKeys())
        {
            yield return (AuditorColorElement)BaseGet(key);
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Config Section

```
public class AuditorColorSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty(nameof(AuditorColors), IsRequired = true, IsDefaultCollection = true)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(AuditorColorElementCollection),
        AddItemName = "add",
        ClearItemsName = "clear",
        RemoveItemName = "remove")]
    public AuditorColorElementCollection AuditorColors
    {
        get { return ((AuditorColorElementCollection)(base[nameof(AuditorColors)])); }
        set { base[nameof(AuditorColors)] = value; }
    }

    public AuditorColorSection()
    {
        AuditorColors = new AuditorColorElementCollection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you writing to? Where physically? Does the user running your app have permission to write there?

Comment: I guess this might help you [How to get admin privileges for editing app.config in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3147171/how-to-get-admin-privileges-for-editing-app-config-in-c)

Comment: @mariocatch Writing to ProgramData, but other apps in our suite modify config files just fine that are also stored there.  Is there a difference between the <appSettings> section being modified (which works for our other apps) vs a custom section in terms of permissions?  Also, my app uses log4net which doesn't seem to have an issue writing the log to that location.

Comment: what doe syour app.config look like? Just the section declaration part

Comment: @mariocatch Well its a custom section so it doesn't exist first run, but when its created successfully (Debug mode or run as Admin) it looks like this:
`<section name="AssignedColors" type="TMIAuditorTerritoryExtract.AuditorColorSection, TMIAuditorTerritoryExtract, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not a fan of using methods in the System.Configuration namespace to **write** to config files. *Reading values using methods in the System.Configuration namespace is never a problem.*

Just use LinqToXML instead, at least to check if that is the problem.

I'm guessing your app is installed in `C:\Program Data` so while it could be permissions related I suspect the root cause of the `System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unable to save config to file` is a [lock on the file, use this code to check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/876473/is-there-a-way-to-check-if-a-file-is-in-use/11060322#11060322) if that assumption is correct.

Comment: So I wasn't using `System.Configuration` namespace to write the actual file (file was created by Add-->New Item in VS itself and set to copy to output), but it was just an empty config file with the standard tag of `<configuration>`.  As stated the error occurred when triying to open the file and save changes to it.  What I did that ended up fixing the issue is creating the XML file in code with XML Writer and writing the top level `<configuration>` tag with it.  The remaining of the code was unchanged and yet this time it works. Does that point to your theory of it being locked?

Comment: All the attributes you're using are in the `System.Configuration` namespace, eg [ConfigurationProperty](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationproperty(v=vs.110).aspx). I've had heaps of problems with writing to config files using those types of methods . It was just a hunch/assumption/guess the root cause of why it fails is because the file is locked. If its not permissions related, and not a file not found then the next logical choice is that the file locked. The main point was using LinqToXML or XML Writer instead. I'm glad you got it working.

Comment: Thanks me too, was very confusing and I still don't see the difference between using `System.Configuration` to edit a file created compile time (didn't work) vs a file created at runtime (worked via XMLWriter), but suspect it has something to do with permissions but past that its just speculation.